# Books for learning C# with respect to Exam 70-573 on SharePoint 2010 Application Development

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

My company has asked me to take Exam 70-573 on SharePoint 2010 Application Development.

So the first step for me is to learn C#. Can you guys recommend any books that will help me learn what I need to know so that I can move into learning SharePoint development. Also, should I spend time learning about the .NET framework itself?

I have a lot of programming experience and am good at picking up new languages. I've just never done any .NET development before.

Thanks!

Comment: why people get down voted when asking for a book ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jon Skeet's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471) is the best way to learn C# regardless of how you'll use C# or what exam you might want to pass.

Comment: You can also google online for "c# tutorials" and you will find many only tutorials that will help you be on your way.